# Can a django model have two abstract classes?

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class, billing

I have this models:

```
class BillHeader(models.Model):
    billno = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True)

class BillData(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(_('Price'), max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(_('Amount'), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    [... rest of the model ...]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BillFooter(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(_('Total'), max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)

    [... rest of the model ...]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

`BillData` and `BillFooter` are common to every `BillHeader` so I've marked them as `abstract`. Can I do `class BillHeader(BillData, BillFooter)` or I'm doing something wrong?

I also thought about doing `BillData` the main one, and `BillHeader` `BillFooter` abstract. I don't have any experience on doing data models (at least not complex ones) and I'm a bit lost. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, a Django model can inherit from as many abstract base classes as you like, as long as they don't result in an ambiguous "model resolution order". Think of inheritance as a chain... each class you inherit from is a link in the chain. Inheriting from two base classes is just adding two links to the chain instead of one.

In other words, if your abstract base classes inherit from `models.Model`, then don't try to inherit from both the abstract base class *and* `models.Model` in your `Bill` class. `models.Model` is already in the inheritance chain, so inheriting from it causes chaos in the chain of base classes.

As to how *I* would structure these classes, I would create a model called `Bill` that inherited from `BillHeader`, `BillData`, and `BillFooter`. The reason for this is that I like my Django models to represent discrete objects (e.g. Bill, Article, BlogPost, Photo, etc.)

However, the point of abstract base classes is to be able to add a level of abstraction to common fields and methods so that multiple classes can inherit from them. If you're just creating a Bill class it's somewhat meaningless. If, however, you had Bill, and UnpaidBill, and PaidBill... all of those would have common fields that should appear on all of them and you can save yourself a lot of trouble by abstracting to an ABC.

Hopefully that offers a little insight to what ABC's and inheritance are good for.

Comment: +1 for the explanation about discrete objects. However, I still have a doubt, if I create a Bill class, can it be empty? I mean, with no fields, only inheriting from the ABC's?

Comment: it can indeed. you would just write `pass` indented under the class.

Comment: Heres the docs of the matter with an example of how to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance