# Inheriting multiple abstract classes in Django

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I have two Abstract base classes A and B which both inherit from models.Model.

Now I need to have concrete class C to inherit from A and B.

I read that in the accepted answer of another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144019/can-a-django-model-have-two-abstract-classes#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=Yes%2C%20a%20Django%20model%20can,a%20link%20in%20the%20chain.) that it's not recommended to inherit from two abstract classes that both inherit from models.Model.

I tried looking up for solutions to get around that but found nothing suitable.

Could someone please provide a suggestion how to or if it's okay to inherit from A and B?

**EDIT**

```
class A (models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
  dateofbirth = models.DateField()

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class B (models.Model):
  IDnumber = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
  IDType = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class C (A, B)
  //rest of code
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the models?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to inherit from multiple abstract models

Comment: @IainShelvington I've added an example. That's what I thought as well. However, seeing as to how it was in the accepted answer in the other question, I just want to avoid doing anything that's not recommended

Comment: The answer in the other question was just warning about ambiguous MROs, this will not be an issue for you if you just have your 2 simple base classes

Comment: @IainShelvington I see. Thanks for that. I'll go ahead then :)